# Javascript object and this

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, this

```
function robot(robotId) {
  this.id = robotId;
  this.parts = new Array();

  this.collectParts = function() {
    $.getJSON('some/url', function(json) {
      for(i in json.responses) {
        this.parts = json.responses[i].parts;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

How do I actually assign this.parts?

Comment: Too many of the same response, so I'll leave a comment. There are a couple other ways you could fix this that don't involve a variable. One is the [`jQuery.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) method, which will return a function that will invoke your function but with the correct `this` bound. Another solution would be to use the [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method instead, and set the `context:` parameter, which allows you to set the value of `this` in the callbacks.

Comment: If you do use a variable, I'd place it inside the `collectParts` function. Doing this, or using the above approaches will let you place your `collectParts` method on `robot.prototype`, so you're not recreating the same function with every instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assign a reference to `this` (when it's in the proper scope) to a variable and use that variable in the function which has changed the scope of `this`. In the modified version of your code below, `robotInstance` is the variable I've opted to use:

```
function robot(robotId) {
  var robotInstance = this;

  this.id = robotId;
  this.parts = new Array();

  this.collectParts = function() {
    $.getJSON('some/url', function(json) {
      for(i in json.responses) {
        robotInstance.parts = json.responses[i].parts;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**Edit:** I had written this modification last night, then decided not to post it.  But based on the comment to your question by @Ӫ_._Ӫ, I decided I'd show you the way I would write your code:

```
var robot = function( robotId )
{
  this.id = robotId;
  this.parts = [];
};
robot.prototype = {
  collectParts: function()
  {
    var robotInstance = this;

    $.getJSON(
      'some/url',
      function( json )
      {
        var i,
            responses = json.responses;
        for( i in responses )
        {
          if( Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call( responses, i ) )
          {
            robotInstance.parts = responses[i].parts;
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: He beat you by 3 seconds. Thank you.

Comment: That's not what I see when I sort by oldest, but no big deal to me so long as you accept _a_ correct answer.

Comment: Just a couple comments before you get my vote. ;) My guess is that each robot instance should have its own `parts` Array. If so, you won't want that on the prototype. Also, I'm curious about the reason for the long form `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call( responses, i )` instead of `responses.hasOwnProperty( i );`. I personally wouldn't use `O.hOP` at all, but I understand that's a style choice.

Comment: You know, I use that trick of putting things on the prototype a lot, and never considered that it was probably referenced rather than copied on instantiation.  That said, I've not had any problems arise from it either...I will have to reinvestigate. In the mean time, I will move it in my answer. I can't remember all the reasons for the long form of `hasOwnProperty`, but Crockford gives a few. The primary being that someone might have modified the inherited `hasOwnProerty` in the object on which you're checking `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ You're absolutely right about the `parts` on the prototype. I forgot all about that as I am often using jQuery's `extend` to build prototype objects and it causes a copy rather than a reference. I have to keep that in mind! Thanks, Jim.

Comment: JAAulde: Yeah since the `prototype` is a single object referenced by the instances, it's usually correct to have mutable types directly on the instance. +1 for the update.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ - thanks for the vote, and for the respectable way in which you questioned the answer. Awesome SO experience!

Answer (score 6):

To access `this` inside jQuery functions, you need to assign it to another variable, for instance, `self = this;` then replace `this` with `self`.

Answer (score 4):

Just assign this to another variable e.g that

```
function robot(robotId) {
  var that = this; 
  that.id = robotId;
  that.parts = new Array();

  that.collectParts = function() {
    $.getJSON('some/url', function(json) {
      for(i in json.responses) {
        that.parts = json.responses[i].parts;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have to wait 11 minutes.

Answer (score 4):

You can capture "this" in a "that" variable so that it can be used inside the scope of the callback of your $.getJSON

```
function robot(robotId) {
  this.id = robotId;
  this.parts = new Array();
  var that = this;
  this.collectParts = function() {
    $.getJSON('some/url', function(json) {
      for(i in json.responses) {
        that.parts = json.responses[i].parts;
      }
    });
  }
}
```